# Which configuration options are preferred in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to enquire that which configuration option is given priority in spark? Is it the configuration file or the options we manually specify when running the spark-submit shell?
What if I have different options for executor memory in my configuration file and I specify a different value while running the spark-submit shell?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *Spark* (1.5.0) [configuration page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties) clearly states what the priorities are:

> Properties set directly on the SparkConf take highest precedence, then flags passed to spark-submit or spark-shell, then options in the spark-defaults.conf file.

So this is the priority order (from highest to lowest):

- Properties set on the *SparkConf* (in program).
- Flags passed to `spark-submit` or `spark-shell`.
- Options set in the `spark-defaults.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @Mikel Urkia